# After Installation of Visual studio 2013 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8, partitioning

After the completion of visual studio 2013 it is taking too much time after first restart. I don't know what to do.Its like just stuck on window screen

Comment: We need more information.  What exactly is "to much time"

Answer (score 1):

Please try disabling the "Hardware Graphics Acceleration" in Visual Studio. Please follow the below steps and check the outcome.

Tools > Options > Environment > General > deselect the "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance", "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" and "Enable rich client visual experience" options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would this option cause his computer to boot slower than normal?